# Access a visual element inside a collectionview in .net maui

Tags: .net, uicollectionview, maui, visualtreehelper

I have this CollectionView. Inside are ellipses. I can't access them from code-behind. They are there, I can see them through the debugger. They are like (CollectionView.base.base.base.base.base.base.base.Children) but for everything I tried I can't get them.
And I think there is no VisualTreeHelper class in .net maui unlike wpf

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SolutionColors}" 
            SelectionMode="None"    
            x:Name="solutionColorsCollectionView">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{Binding NumberOfCircles}"
                 HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
                 VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60">
                <Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CircleColorsViewModel}}, Path=SetSolutionColorCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding Index}" />
                </Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Directly messing with the visual elements of a templated control is generally a really bad idea

Comment: When they are correctly colored by the player, I will have them bounce one by one, have them do a little animation.

Answer (score -1):

solutionColorsCollectionView.GetVisualTreeDescendants() did it.

Comment: Yes, the good old visual tree. So much work done to implement MVVM correctly, and thrown out of the window at the end by walking through VisualElements and manually animating them. I advise you to check out triggers.

Comment: Disclaimer for people looking for Answers this is 100% not the way to do this, You should never play around with VisualTree's

Comment: I know about triggers, they change the visual state of a control based on a condition but can they also be used to animate the control?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).